# Flutter Navigate to Independent screen from BottomNavigation bar

Tags: flutter, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Following is my code which i am using for bottom navigation

```
class NaviBottom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NaviBottomState createState() => _NaviBottomState();
}

class _NaviBottomState extends State<NaviBottom> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeScreen(),
    AddProperties(),
    MyFavProperties(),
    MyProfile(),
    Login()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Open Houze")),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text('First')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.mail), title: new Text('Second')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Third')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Forth')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Fifith'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

In this my first three tab views to be shown with bottom navigation bar whereas when I click on the last two tabs I need to Navigate and show other screens without BottomNavigation bar,

Comment: hi there, I have a question, how do you plan to navigate back to first three tabs? I would recommend you to navigate to 'tabless' screens from first three tabs

Comment: You can push a screen over the tabbed screen using Navigator.of(context).push(). It'll also bring you back to the tabbed screen once you press the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void onTabTapped(int index) {
  if(index >= 0 && index < 3)
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  if(index == 3)
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FourthPage()),
    );
  if(index == 4)
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FifthPage()),
    );
}
```

N.B : Dart has **type inference**, meaning that you don't need to annotate the type if it's explicit. So you can just type `final _children` and remove the `List<Widget>`.